# XSL: How to parse huge text file (several GB)

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I had a template that parse an industrial system export file to xml.
For a new job I want to reuse it but the file is too big (4 Gig and growing every day)

The original template made use of unparsed-text, analyze-string, ...
The issue is only with unparsed-text and maybe the computer available memory.
the only solution I found is to split the file before the xsl processing but it is not very efficient because it takes too much time.

Is it possible to load only a portion of a file with in xsl template?

Comment: In XSLT 3 there is streamed processing of XML input possible where the processor streams through an XML input in a forwards only mode only "materializing" the current node and its attributes and keeping a record of ancestors. But as for plain text files you read with `unparsed-text`, I am not sure there is any support for streamed or chunk-wise processing. I think the `unparsed-text-lines` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-unparsed-text-lines would in theory allow some streamed processing, not sure whether Saxon EE supports that.

Comment: It would also help if you clarify what kind of "portion" (a particular line) of the text file you want to load in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.9/hej/net/sf/saxon/functions/UnparsedTextLines.java it seems if you use the function `unparsed-text-lines` in Saxon 9.9 (even HE) it avoids pulling the complete file into memory but instead builds a line based iterator so I suppose if you use `xsl:iterate select="unparsed-text-lines('foo.txt')"` and then only process/store/accumulate the line(s) you need and perhaps finally break with `xsl:break` when done with the relevant lines you can reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I check this.
Chunk of text is actually a header of 2 lines followed by data encapsulated between []. The amount of headers is unknown as well as the amount of data lines.
MODULE TAG=xxx 
user=xxx time=xxx
[
    data=yyy
  unknown quantity of lines
]

Comment: @ocsk7, perhaps using an approach alike  `<xsl:for-each-group select="unparsed-text-lined('input.tx')" group-starting-with=".[starts-with(., 'MODULE')]">` helps breaking that stuff up into managable "chunks" inside of the XSLT code. Feel free to edit your question and show some more details of what your input looks like, what your current code looks like and what kind of processing and result you need for that textual data.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the text file  as I am not the owner.
But it would be something like this

Comment: MODULE_INSTANCE TAG="PI-100" PLANT_AREA="U TILITIES/PC/p-100" MODULE_CLASS name="AI" CATEGORY=""
 user="Olivier" time=1561702805/* "28-Jun-2019 08:20:05" */
{
  DESCRIPTION="Pressure"
  WORK_IN_PROGRESS=F
  PERIOD=1
  PRY_CONTROL_DISPLAY="P-100"
  INSTRUMENT_AREA_DISPLAY="pressure_FP"
  DETAIL_DISPLAY="pressure_DT"
  }

Comment: I need to transform this to XML which is quite obvious.
Martin I try the unparsed--text-line and also read about parsing in another of your post. It works fine but then I realized Oxygen XML editor build the all of the node into memory before it writes the output file.
So I still have the same memory issue.
I should find a way to serialize the output at different step. 
Do you know a way to do this?
Is the xsl:result-document the way to go with some kind of recursive or grouping different type of nodes like "library", "Classes", "Instances", "hardware"...

Comment: Is "but then I realized Oxygen XML editor build the all of the node into memory before it writes the output file" based on documentation or advice from the oXygen people? As for  Saxon 9, as far as I undestand it creates nothing more than serialization events to emit XML, unless you store nodes to further process them. But in general it seems for better advice you could ask on the Saxon help forum on https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/boards/3 or add a Saxon tag here in the hope that they pick it up.